# cache folder setting in phpbb3

Tags: caching, config, phpbb3

Can anyone tell me where the config of cache folder is for phpbb3? I need to use a different folder due to my isp and can't find where i can point the folder to another location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

includes/acm/acm_file.php

```
/**
* Set cache path
*/
function acm()
{
    global $phpbb_root_path;
    $this->cache_dir = $phpbb_root_path . 'cache/';
}
```